# OLED screen color aging still an issue?

Tags: display, external-display, tv

OLED colors are organic and they can fade. At least that's what I learned a few years back. Is this still a problem in today's displays?

This year is the year of OLED TVs and I consider getting one. A TV should IMHO last longer than a smartphone.

Answer (score 2):

Burn in seems to be less of an issue these days. On a television you will likely not be seeing the same image constantly like you may on a desktop PC. If you are showing the same image alot of the time you may still want to worry though.

I have experienced burnin on a samsung galaxy s3 but it was only after the screen was left constantly on for 4 months with the same nearly identical pixels on all the time. No such issues with the Galaxy S4 after 3 years, though not being subjected to the same image on constantly.

A few discussions:

http://www.avsforum.com/forum/40-oled-technology-flat-panels-general/2341817-reviewed-com-s-oled-burn-article.html

http://televisions.reviewed.com/features/what-to-know-about-oled-screen-burn-in-problems-causes-image-retention